# How can I make an application on pc as a bluetooth low energy device?

Tags: core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I try to make an app on iPhone which can receive date from ble device.
I've read the api from Apple.

But I want to send this data from PC with ble dongle.

There are some samples for receiving data from ble device.

But I need to make the pc simulate ble device.

Is that possible? And if it is, how can I do taht?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you own a Mac(, considering that you are making an iPhone app), you can create a OS X project that provides GATT and GAP with CoreBluetooth. See the sample code CoreBluetooth: Health Thermometer. Note that the sample code serves as a Central, however, you need to implement a Peripheral with a `CBPeripheralManager` instance and other delegates.

In your Mac OS X app, you need to provide a characteristic with `CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicate` or `CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify`.

In your iPhone app, you need to set this characteristic notifying.